# PickerView loading data issue

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, uipickerview

I am loading data from server which is working fine without problem and I can see `res` value in the `NSLog` as

```
2013-11-19 16:22:48.799 Paaa[4278:a0b] res ( { "choice_name" = "DATA0"; }, { "choice_name" = "DATA1"; }, { "choice_name" = "DATA2"; } )The problem is I can't view it in the `pickerView` It always indicate to `return [res count]` as EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So please where would be my problem?
```

.H:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *res;
```

.M:

```
- (void)requestPos:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request{

    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Create a dictionary from the JSON string
NSDictionary *result = [jsonString JSONValue];
[jsonString release];

    CXMLDocument *doc = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:[result objectForKey:@"Response"] options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

NSArray *nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/root" error:nil];

    NSArray *nodes3 = NULL;
    nodes3 = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/root/cl_choicelist/cl_choice" error:nil];

    NSLog(@"node3%@", nodes3);

    //  we will put parsed data in an a array
    res = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (CXMLElement *node in nodes3) {
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    int counter;
    for(counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
        //  common procedure: dictionary with keys/values from XML node
        [item setObject:[[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[node childAtIndex:counter] name]];
    }

    //  and here it is - attributeForName! Simple as that.
    [item setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"choice_name"] stringValue] forKey:@"choice_name"];  // <------ this magical arrow is pointing to the area of interest.

    [res addObject:item];
    [item release];
}
    NSLog(@"res %@", res);
    [res release];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [res count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
return [[res objectAtIndex:row]objectForKey:@"choice_name"];
}

- (IBAction)openPickerView{

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 492)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: comment this  //[res release];

Comment: As First you releasing your res array again try to acces it. So It will give exception like. Message sent to deallocated instance. So don't release "res" array as this is going to use in future.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre it works, after commenting [res release].

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre : you missed 15 more reputations..:)

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre Make it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: No problem, I am happy with even my comments are useful to get solution.

Comment: But I have to accept a question otherwise it will be not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't release `res` at the end of `requestPos:`

If [Bhumeshwer katre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673063/bhumeshwer-katre) won't write his answer, then I will :)

Comment: Why I don'y release it at the end of `requestPos:` ?

Comment: 1) Because you should be using ARC, and 2) Because you want to use it later, don't you? I thought that's what Bhumeshwer was saying and that you said fixed your problem.

Comment: Ok. Then where exactly should I release it?

Comment: That depends on where and when you use it. You need to go and learn about memory management and manual reference counting.